# Approximating integral with variable in the bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

It is very easy to approximate

$$\int_0^k f(x) \ dx$$

when we don't know the indefinite integral of $f(x)$. Visually it's clear that we can approximate the area using rectangles, and this gives us a good formula to approximate the integral. Using an $x$-spacing of $\delta$, we can say:

$$\int_0^k f(x) \ dx \approx \delta\left((f(\frac{\delta}{2}) + f(\frac{3\delta}{2}) + \ldots +  f({k - \frac{\delta}{2}})\right)$$

This is a clean formula that has accuracy dependent on $\delta$.

Consider a similar problem: find the minimal $x$ such that

$$k = \int_0^x f(\chi) \ d\chi$$

when we don't know the indefinite integral of $f(x)$.

Visually, we can take a value for $x$, calculate the area to that point, and adjust $x$ until we get the desired total area. However, there doesn't seem to be a nice formula with an "accuracy" parameter.

Furthermore, what if my $k = 1$, but my function has area $\le 1$ until some large $x$? Then it seems convergence happens slowly, or one might conclude there's no answer if you don't look "far enough".

Is there any nice formula or way to approach the second problem so that it's mathematically tractable?